# Weird variable issue in python 2.7 on linux (pygame/pillow)

Tags: variables, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am using python and there is a weird issue:

```
pygame.init()
f = 1

def setf(widget, buttonToggled):
    f = int(buttonToggled)

def getf():
    if f == 1: return ImageFilter.BLUR
    if f == 2: return ImageFilter.CONTOUR
    if f == 3: return ImageFilter.DETAIL
    if f == 4: return ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE
    if f == 5: return ImageFilter.EMBOSS
    if f == 6: return ImageFilter.SMOOTH
    if f == 7: return ImageFilter.SHARPEN

def doFilter(widget, buttonToggled):
    global ip
    if winBook.get_current_page() == 2 and f == 1:
        ip = pygame.image.fromstring(Image.fromstring("RGBA",(320,294),pygame.image.tostring(ip, "RGBA")).filter(getf()).convert("RGBA").tostring("raw", "RGBA"), (320,294), "RGBA")
        upd()

applyButton.connect("clicked", doFilter, f)
filterBlur.connect("toggled", setf, 1)
filterContour.connect("toggled", setf, 2)
filterDetail.connect("toggled", setf, 3)
filterEE.connect("toggled", setf, 4)
filterEmboss.connect("toggled", setf, 5)
filterSmooth.connect("toggled", setf, 6)
filterSharpen.connect("toggled", setf, 7)
```

Of course I obviously have created the objects from a gtk.Builder, from a glade file. I also have a pygame image called "ip" and a pygame window.

My problem is when I toggle a button other that the filterBlur (which is a radio button), for some reason getf somehow still returns ImageFilter.BLUR. I have previously put print f in setf and getf and both of them return the correct value. I am too much of a noob to do debugging with threading (having one thread constantly report f while another runs the program).  What is going on? Is f changing back to 1, or is it inside getf?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `global f` statement inside `setf`. Otherwise the `f` setter function just creates a local variable